# Unzipping A file in vb

Tags: vb.net, unzip, shell32

I get exception when I try to unzip a file

When I remove the try I receive:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    Try
        Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()
        '
        'Create directory in which you will unzip your files .
        '
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath & "/Packs/SkyNet/mods")
        '
        'Declare the folder where the files will be extracted
        '
        Dim output As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace(Application.StartupPath & "/Packs/SkyNet/mods")
        '
        'Declare your input zip file as folder  .
        '
        Dim input As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace(Application.StartupPath & "/Downloads/SkyNet.zip")
        '
        'Extract the files from the zip file using the CopyHere command .
        '
        output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath & "/Config/SkyNet.pack", "SkyNet Installed", False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could Not Extract Pack: SkyNet", "SkyNet Launcher: Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath & "/Config/SkyNet.pack", "SkyNet Not Installed", False)
    End Try
```

I have tried setting **output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)** to **output.CopyHere(input.Items, 148)** but returns same error.

(148 is the number of items inside the zip)

Comment: You need to start with understanding the error message.  Once you figure that out you'll be in a much better position.  Error messages do have purpose and meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path is invalid for the input or output folder, it will cause this error. Check your paths before using them in the dim statement.

Comment: Okay yes for some reason the path was wrong.

I figured that Forward Slashes would work, but I switched to backslashes and it worked 100%. I did not know that mattered because I have used forward slashes before.